# How to handle global things with Clean Architecture in Flutter apps?

Tags: flutter, dart, tdd, flutter-test, clean-architecture

I have completed **Reso Coder** tutorial about **Clean Architecture with TDD in Flutter Apps**. But there are two points interesting for me:

1. If we have global widgets like `Loading`, `Failure`, `Empty Case` and so on, in which layer and how we can store them to access from any feature? is it okay to create folder like `widgets` in `core` folder to store these widgets?
2. If we have the same API calls, or same local data in different pages, in different features, how can we store them? is it okay to create independent features that have not views itself, just contains `domain` and `data` layer for other features?

This is my repository:
https://github.com/thisisyusub/tdd-learn-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By checking your repo I'm guessing you are talking about your `FailureWidget` and `LoadingWidget` and by "global widgets" you meant widgets used in multiple features of your application. Now to answer your questions :

In my opinion you can definitely put widgets shared in multiple features in the `core/` folder but I would recommend to keep some sort of coherence with your different layers. By that I mean that widgets should be putted inside a `presentation` subfolder because only your presentation layer should depend on those.

```
lib/
  |- core/
  |  |- presentation/
  |  |  |- loading_widget.dart
  |  |  |- failure_widget.dart
```

Same goes for API calls you want to re-use in multiple features, you can put them inside a `data/` subfolder of `core/`.

```
lib/
  |- core/
  |  |- data/
  |  |- data_sources/
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have assumed the same, it is not clear.

Comment: I agree, personally I am not a big fan of how Reso Coder is splitting his folders into features, I prefer having only one folder for each of `domain`, `data` and `presentation` so I don't need to put shared code in the `core/` folder.